Starting Windows Sandbox with mapped folder from network share on Windows 11 24H2
Under Windows 11 23H2, I was able to start Windows Sandbox with a mapped folder that lived in a network share on the host with something like the following:
<Configuration>
    <MappedFolders>
        <MappedFolder>
            <HostFolder>\\foo\bar\baz</HostFolder>
        </MappedFolder>
    </MappedFolders>
</Configuration>

Upon upgrading to Windows 11 24H2, Windows Sandbox fails to start with the error Error 0x8007052e. The user name or password is incorrect..
I've tried mapping the network share to a drive letter on the host and then mapping that to the sandbox, but receive the same error. I've had the above working on three computers with 23H2 and they've all started failing with the same error on 24H2.
This is for a NAS on my network - not another Windows computer - with credentials remembered in the host system, if that matters.
Has anyone else run into this, and does anyone have any suggestions about how to deal with it?
EDIT:
Opened bug report with MS Sandbox team here:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Sandbox/issues/63
